# Returning a json element from a webpage located in a config file

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Web scraping newbie here. I am currently using Selenium to try to extract the matchCentreData element in the following html element. However, it looks like this element is located within a dictionary.

```js
<script>
        require.config.params["args"] = {
            matchId:1485276,
            matchCentreData: {"playerIdNameDictionary":{"29463":"Willian","334087":"Gabriel Magalhães","125209":"Mohamed Elneny","73078":"Alexandre Lacazette","44120":"Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang","80921":"Shkodran Mustafi","92173":"Bernd Leno","141841":"Rúnar Alex Rúnarsson","125211":"Héctor Bellerín","144890":"Dani Ceballos","89401":"Granit Xhaka","255169":"Ainsley Maitland-Niles","288795":"Rob Holding","342563":"Joseph Willock","345845":"Eddie Nketiah","363686":"Emile Smith Rowe","367185":"Bukayo Saka","297403":"Kieran Tierney","84129":"Matej Vydra","74606":"Kevin Long","366743":"Jimmy Dunne","93473":"Robbie Brady","24148":"Erik Pieters","73380":"Chris Wood","33386":"Ashley Barnes","33891":"Jay Rodriguez","79050":"Ashley Westwood","80067":"Matthew Lowton","357427":"Dwight McNeil","94935":"Ben Mee","105720":"Nick Pope","107462":"Charlie Taylor","131464":"James Tarkowski","138929":"Josh Brownhill","300567":"Bailey Peacock-Farrell","369466":"Josh Benson"},"periodMinuteLimits":{"1":45,"2":90,"3":105,"4":120},"timeStamp":"2020-12-14 13:26:01","attendance":2000,"venueName":"Emirates Stadium","referee":{"officialId":131,"firstName":"Graham"
```

I did attempt to use the execute_script method to return that

```py
driver.get(url) 
matchCentredata = driver.execute_script("return require.config.params['args']")
print(matchCentredata)
```

but I get the following error: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'args' of undefined

Is there an alternative way to access this element?

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the page source to a variable and use beautifulsoup4 to parse the html
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py#L798

I am no expert in regular expression, you can do better with the below example.

Example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
  <html>
  <script>
       require.config.params["args"] = {
        matchId:1485276,
        matchCentreData: {"playerIdNameDictionary":{"29463":"Willian","334087":"Gabriel Magalhães","125209":"Mohamed Elneny","73078":"Alexandre Lacazette","44120":"Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang","80921":"Shkodran Mustafi","92173":"Bernd Leno","141841":"Rúnar Alex Rúnarsson","125211":"Héctor Bellerín","144890":"Dani Ceballos","89401":"Granit Xhaka","255169":"Ainsley Maitland-Niles","288795":"Rob Holding","342563":"Joseph Willock","345845":"Eddie Nketiah","363686":"Emile Smith Rowe","367185":"Bukayo Saka","297403":"Kieran Tierney","84129":"Matej Vydra","74606":"Kevin Long","366743":"Jimmy Dunne","93473":"Robbie Brady","24148":"Erik Pieters","73380":"Chris Wood","33386":"Ashley Barnes","33891":"Jay Rodriguez","79050":"Ashley Westwood","80067":"Matthew Lowton","357427":"Dwight McNeil","94935":"Ben Mee","105720":"Nick Pope","107462":"Charlie Taylor","131464":"James Tarkowski","138929":"Josh Brownhill","300567":"Bailey Peacock-Farrell","369466":"Josh Benson"},"periodMinuteLimits":{"1":45,"2":90,"3":105,"4":120},"timeStamp":"2020-12-14 13:26:01","attendance":2000,"venueName":"Emirates Stadium","referee":{"officialId":131,"firstName":"Graham"
  </script>
  </html>
 """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
script_str = soup.script.string.strip()
match = re.search('matchCentreData:(.*)$', script_str)
print(match.group(0))
```

**Output**

```
matchCentreData: {"playerIdNameDictionary":{"29463":"Willian","334087":"Gabriel Magalhães","125209":"Mohamed Elneny","73078":"Alexandre Lacazette","44120":"Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang","80921":"Shkodran Mustafi","92173":"Bernd Leno","141841":"Rúnar Alex Rúnarsson","125211":"Héctor Bellerín","144890":"Dani Ceballos","89401":"Granit Xhaka","255169":"Ainsley Maitland-Niles","288795":"Rob Holding","342563":"Joseph Willock","345845":"Eddie Nketiah","363686":"Emile Smith Rowe","367185":"Bukayo Saka","297403":"Kieran Tierney","84129":"Matej Vydra","74606":"Kevin Long","366743":"Jimmy Dunne","93473":"Robbie Brady","24148":"Erik Pieters","73380":"Chris Wood","33386":"Ashley Barnes","33891":"Jay Rodriguez","79050":"Ashley Westwood","80067":"Matthew Lowton","357427":"Dwight McNeil","94935":"Ben Mee","105720":"Nick Pope","107462":"Charlie Taylor","131464":"James Tarkowski","138929":"Josh Brownhill","300567":"Bailey Peacock-Farrell","369466":"Josh Benson"},"periodMinuteLimits":{"1":45,"2":90,"3":105,"4":120},"timeStamp":"2020-12-14 13:26:01","attendance":2000,"venueName":"Emirates Stadium","referee":{"officialId":131,"firstName":"Graham"
```